# How to GPS Start and Stop depending upon my application?

Tags: android

I want to implement whenever I launch my android
application,that time I want to start gps,

Whenever I close
application, I want to stop gps in device. How to implement
this concept in my application ?

Comment: You should be starting GPS to perform some sort of function, such as getting the user's location. You should not start it every time your application starts and ends. You should start it whenever you need it for a reason. What is it you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @I want get user's current lat,lon from device,so i need GPS

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to remove the LocationListener in all onPause methods of your Activities. You then can restart the listening in your onResume methods.

If you don't remove the listener in the onPause method the GPS will be active even if your app is the paused in the background. See the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

John, you need to use the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) class. Here is a [tutorial on how to get the users location](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2).

Answer (score 1):

First add bellow Class and interface to your application.

```
   public class GPSManager
    {
        private static final int gpsMinTime = 500;
        private static final int gpsMinDistance = 0;

        private LocationManager locationManager = null;
        private LocationListener locationListener = null;
        private GPSCallback gpsCallback = null;

        public GPSManager()
        {
            locationListener = new LocationListener()
            {
                public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider)
                {
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider)
                {
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras)
                {
                }

                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
                {
                    if (location != null && gpsCallback != null)
                    {
                        Log.e("if location "+location,"if gpscallback"+gpsCallback);
                        gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("else location "+location,"else gpscallback"+gpsCallback);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public void startListening(final Activity activity)
        {
            if (locationManager == null)
            {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }

            final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            final String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                        GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
            }
            else
            {
                final List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

                for (final String provider : providers)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                            GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }

        public void stopListening()
        {
            try
            {
                if (locationManager != null && locationListener != null)
                {
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                }

                locationManager = null;
            }
            catch (final Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public void setGPSCallback(final GPSCallback gpsCallback)
        {
            this.gpsCallback = gpsCallback;
        }

        public GPSCallback getGPSCallback()
        {
            return gpsCallback;
        }
  }
```

Interface:

```
public interface GPSCallback
{
    public abstract void onGPSUpdate(Location location);

}
```

then implement this interface in your activity and also add below code in your activity

```
gpsmanager=new GPSManager();
        gpsmanager.startListening(YourActicvityname.this);
        gpsmanager.setGPSCallback(this);
```

To stop GPS call gpsmanager.stopListening() at  where you want to close the application

Comment: Dont forget to add permissions in manifest file,and dont forget to accept answer if it helps you.